# break line on xamarin forms picker

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, picker

My picker shows the title text in this way:

[image]

The rest of the text is showed under when it should be appear by side, filling the picker space (the alice blue box)....it's occures only on android devices. 
how can I solve that? I am using xamarin forms and my picker has a custom renderer, but by default, the title is showed this way, as you can see above...

Comment: Please post your code.